# where/how to find/extract official android os (open source) translation/localization/glossary strings

Tags: android, localization, operating-system, translation, extract

Since the open source android (https://source.android.com) is available in multiple languages, can I somehow find/extract all the translated strings in the OS so I can use them as a reference for my own app's translation? (for example for error messages...)

Or is this list available somewhere?

Probably harder to get, but I'd also like to ask the same question for the official non-open source version...

FYI, I'm not really a developer, just a translator..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Or is this list available somewhere?

Much of it is on your hard drive.

Go to `platforms/.../data/res/` inside of your Android SDK, where `...` is a directory based on the Android version you want (e.g., `android-25` for Android 7.1). There, you will see a set of resource directories, just like the ones that you might have in your own project. This includes hundreds upon hundreds of `values-.../` directories, mostly for various languages. Those will each have a `strings.xml` file with various strings from the Android framework and elsewhere within Android.

AOSP apps will have their own translations, and you would need to rummage around [those projects](https://android.googlesource.com/) for theirs.

Comment: thanks! can I somehow get these xml files if I don't have the android sdk on the computer I am using at the moment?

Comment: @gavurman: Um, the simplest thing would be to download the Android SDK. Most of them will be [here in the AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.0_r4/core/res/res/) for casual browsing. You could `git clone` all of the `frameworks/base` project, I suppose, but that might be larger than the SDK.